# How do I get a camera icon on my lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens, 4.2-jelly-bean

I've seen screenshots from Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) that have a camera icon besides the unlock icon on the lockscreen (see below).

My Nexus 4 (latest Jelly Bean, 4.2.1) has a camera widget on its lockscreen instead, but I find it sometimes hard to open. (As long as the lock symbol is pulsing, the swipe has to be started from the very edge. If you are already widget selection mode, it is easier.)

Is there anyway to add the camera icon (or any other icons) to the unlock circle? In stock, with apps, or with any mods?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You could try [WidgetLocker Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker). It lets you add app shortcuts on your lockscreen.

*It replaces your lockscreen though.*

Answer (score 2):

Go to
**Settings**-->**Lock Screen**-->**Slider Shortcuts**-->*Swipe to any side*--> Click on "**Empty**"-->Select "**Applications**"-->**Camera**

Now you can see a camera Icon on Lock Screen.

Comment: I don't see settings for Lock Screen on android 4.2.1. What phone did you use to provide these instructions?

Comment: Are you using Stock ROM or Custom?